# Webapi not serializing return object

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Hi im building a test application in web-api but my returned object is not being serialized

Controller

```
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.Linq;
            using System.Web;
            using System.Web.Mvc;
            using Thoughts.Models;
            using Newtonsoft.Json;
            namespace Thoughts.Controllers
            {
            public class TagsController : Controller
            {
                //
                // GET: /Tags/

                public ActionResult Index()
                {
                    return View();
                }


                public Message test(){
                    Message msg = new Message();
                    msg.Content = "jo";
                    return msg;
                }
            }
            }
```

Message Model

```
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.Linq;
            using System.Web;

            namespace Thoughts.Models
            {
            [Serializable]
            public class Message //: NamedObject
            {
                string content;

                public string Content
                {
                    get { return content; }
                    set { content = value; }
                }
                /*public NamedObject User;
                public string timestamp;
                public List<NamedObject> tags;
                public Guid communityid;
                public List<Message> comments;
                public int commentCount;
                public string parent;*/
            }
            }
```

Router Config

```
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.Linq;
            using System.Web;
            using System.Web.Mvc;
            using System.Web.Routing;

            namespace HelloWebAPI
            {
                public class RouteConfig
                {
                    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
                    {
                        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

                        routes.MapRoute(
                            name: "Default",
                            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
```

WebApiConfig

```
            using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Web.Http;

        namespace Thoughts
        {
            public static class WebApiConfig
            {
                public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
                {
                    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                        name: "DefaultApi",
                        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                    );
                }
            }
        }
```

also my /api url does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inherit from `ApiController` for Web API (Web API controllers are separate from MVC controllers):

```
public class TagsController : ApiController {

        [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public Message test(){
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.Content = "jo";
                return msg;
        }

 }
```

Since your HTTP route is `api/{controller}/{action}/{id}`

You can now invoke it: `/api/tags/test`

Finally, for Web API you don't need `[Serializable]` attribute.

Comment: thanks will test this at home, seems like the solution. ye i added [Serializable] because i thought it may be the issue :)